# Visualforce: Can't access archived static resource

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I'm trying to access some static resource in my visualforce page. I have uploaded a zip file named pqGrid. It's structure is like so:

```
- pqgrid.min.js
- pggrid.min.css
- images/
    --image1.png
    --image2.png
```

Following the directions in the sf docs on [referencing a static resource](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm), I tried the following:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pqgrid.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pqgrid.min.css')}"/>
```

Onloading the page, I get a 404:

> GET
>   https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/resource/7975978979000/pqGrid/pqgrid.min.js
>   404 (Not Found) GET
>   https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/resource/7975978979000/pqGrid/pqgrid.min.css

I've even tried just referencing an image:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'images/cross.png')}"/>
```

and same 404:

> GET
>   https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/resource/7975978979000/pqGrid/images/cross.png
>   404 (Not Found)

I've made sure that the resource cache control is public

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT

Tried putting all the files into another directory, so it is now pqGrid/stash/[*files]

When I get the 404 not found:

> GET
>   https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/resource/1430434594000/pqGrid/stash/pqgrid.min.css

I tried playing with this url. Trying to navigate to just /stash/ throws a ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE error. Navigating to just /pqGrid/ let's me download the stuff. Trying to go directly to the file, /pqGrid/stash/file.js I just get a blank page.

So the zip is definitely on salesforce, but something is up with accessing it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

You need the top level folder name too. Change

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pgrid.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pqgrid.min.css')}"/>
```

To:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pqGrid/pqgrid.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pqGrid/pqgrid.min.css')}"/>
```

Actually, to be more accurate, you need to change the second parameter to start with the folder name before you zipped it up.

I tend to try to name my static resources the exact same name as the unzipped folder name -ie

```
my_resources/mycss.css
            /myjavascript.js
```

I would name the static resource `my_resources` and refer to as:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.my_resources, 'my_resources/myjavascript.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.my_resources, 'my_resources/mycss.css')}"/>
```

**EDIT** Looking at my static resources in SublimeText, I can see that Salesforce actually makes you a folder with the name of your static resource when you upload your static resource. So if you didn't want to have the name repeated, you could select all your resources on your filesystem (but not their enclosing folder) and archive them together.

This would make your existing structure work.

Comment: Not working. If you look at the 404's I'm getting, you'll see that pqGrid directory is autoadded, like you mentioned. I still tried adding pqGrid to the file dir, like you suggested, making it URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'pqGrid/pqgrid.min.css'), didn't work (and now searched for pqGrid/pqGrid/resource). I also tried saving all files into a folder, stash, and then rezipping and uploading. I then tried URLFOR($Resource.pqGrid, 'stash/pqgrid.min.css'), still a 404.

Comment: Try changing those direct to resource urls in your browser address bar - you should be able to fiddle with them until you get them right - oh and make sure your newly uploaded resource has cache control == public

Comment: I noticed a typo in your naming of files in the question - pgGrid instead of pqGird

Comment: Trying to play around with them directly - I just get a blank page regardless of what I put in. Also, I'm not sure what to add/delete, the URL looks fine: https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/resource/7975978979000/pqGrid/stash/pqgrid.min.css

Comment: First, see if you can just download the first part of the url: https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/resource/7975978979000/pqGrid - oh and are you sure it's pqGrid, not pgGrid? If you can, then it's something in your path that is not specified correctly.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: See edited question